# How to get updated HTML radio button in Workflow Inbox?

Tags: workflow, abap

Since I'm so new for workflow, now I'm stuck at on how to get updated radio button of HTML table in Workflow inbox when click decision button.

[image]

STEP 1: ln HTML table, the user can approve or reject WBS by checked radio

STEP 2: When user click confirm, then the workflow will update status for each WBS that shown in the table.

Question:
On STEP 2 - how can I get the HTML text which updated by user action.

For now I've enhanced SAPEVENTS and using 'SAP_WAPI_READ_CONTAINER' to get HTML container.

However, after check the HTML code, the HTML table is not update to user action.

Comment: If it's a standard workflow, please tell us what is its SAP name. If it's custom, please provide more details.

Comment: Hi Sandra Rossi,
It is custom workflow. 
Workflow Designs - After workflow triggered then workflow will get all WBS which have SUBMIT Status in the Project to show in HTML Table.
User can Approve/Reject for each WBS by checking the radio button and Press Confirm as shown in the picture above.

Technical Design: My plan for this workflow is that after user click confirm button, I will load the HTML table from workflow and check HTML code which is radio is checked.
Then send the radio button ID to Decision note and use that code to update WBS status.

Comment: However, it seems that the HTML table code is not updated to user action. So I go for another solution which is enhancing SAPEVENT to get action in HTML table. Then I use 'SAP_WAPI_READ_CONTAINER' to get HTML code from the workflow container and change HTML code to match the user action, then, update workflow container by 'SAP_WAPI_WRITE_CONTAINER' but its return error 900.

Comment: I know how to get the checkbox value from the HTML Viewer control, without enhancing anything. But now your issue is distinct, related to SAP Business Workflow, so please ask another question (no need to talk about HTML Viewer). You can delete this one if you wish.

Comment: Thanks you for help Sandra Rossi.
But I need to ask another question, since, I'm still not understand about your suggestion. If my issue is not about HTML Viewer then what question should I ask then.

Comment: How to read the value of a checkbox in the HTML Viewer control is not the same question as how to write a value to the workflow container, you can write reproducible minimal examples which are completely independent, and I can answer two completely-independent answers too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal program which demonstrates how to get the values of the radio buttons. If the user presses Approve on the first line and Reject on the second line, and presses the button Confirm, the method `on_sapevent` gets `group[1]=approve&group[2]=reject`.

(works in something like ABAP 7.40 SP8)

```
REPORT zdemo.
CLASS lcl_app DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS at_selection_screen_output.
    METHODS on_sapevent FOR EVENT sapevent OF cl_gui_html_viewer
          IMPORTING action frame getdata postdata query_table.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    DATA o_html TYPE REF TO cl_gui_html_viewer.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS lcl_app IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD at_selection_screen_output.
    DATA: l_url  TYPE cndp_url,
          l_text TYPE string.
    IF o_html IS NOT BOUND.
      l_text = '<body><form id="form" method="POST" action="SAPEVENT:submit">'
          && REDUCE string( INIT t = `` FOR I = 1 WHILE i <= 2
             NEXT t = t && |<div><fieldset id="group{ i }">|
                        && |<input type="radio" value="approve" name="group[{ i }]"> Approve |
                        && |<input type="radio" value="reject" name="group[{ i }]"> Reject|
                        && |</fieldset></div>| )
          && '<p><button type= "submit">Confirm</button></p>'
          && '</form></body>'.
      o_html = NEW #( parent = cl_gui_container=>screen0 ).
      SET HANDLER on_sapevent FOR o_html.
      o_html->set_registered_events( events = value #( ( eventid = o_html->m_id_sapevent ) ) ).
      DATA(lt_text) = cl_bcs_convert=>string_to_soli( l_text ).
      o_html->load_data(
        EXPORTING type = 'text' subtype = 'html' size = strlen( l_text )
        IMPORTING assigned_url = l_url
        CHANGING  data_table = lt_text ).
      o_html->show_url( EXPORTING url = l_url ).
    ENDIF.
  ENDMETHOD.
  METHOD on_sapevent.
    CONCATENATE LINES OF postdata INTO data(l_post_data) RESPECTING BLANKS.
    MESSAGE l_post_data TYPE 'I'.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

PARAMETERS dummy.
DATA go_app TYPE REF TO lcl_app.

LOAD-OF-PROGRAM.
  CREATE OBJECT go_app.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  go_app->at_selection_screen_output( ).
```

Comment: Hi is it possible to get the whole HTML code in the current screen?
That's the answer and solution I'm looking for this question. Noted: please accept my apologizes if my bad english make my question doesn't clear enough.

Comment: I don't understand your query. Stack Overflow only answers one simple question at a time. If your question is about HTML Viewer and Inbox at the same time, considering you developed some custom code we don't know, then it's too complex for Stack Overflow, better ask in a general-purpose forum like [SAP Community](https://answers.sap.com/tags/833755570260738661924709785639136).